# C# file extensions

Tags: c#, file

I am attempting to loop through a folder and return files with the  extension .err. However, the extensions vary from .ERR to .Err to .err depending upon what is contained within the file itself. I am using the below;

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"\\" + textBox1.Text + @"\\d$\\", "*.err")
```

Is the above code case sensitive in that it is limited to returning those with .err only?

Comment: Run the code and find out...

Comment: You could have found out your own answer to this question in less time than it took to type out your question...

Comment: must be testing in prod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case In-Sensitive

Windows file system is case insensitive by default.